# responsive website issue in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to make a standard site responsive. So far it works in IE9, Firefox and Chrome, but it fails in IE7 and IE8 even with inline hacks:

http://surfingthebluemarble.com/rtest2.html

What is happening is that in IE7 and IE8 the divs fail to stack when they go to 99% width.

Thanks as always for your help.

umbre

Answer (score 11):

You're using CSS media queries, which don't work in older versions of IE.

You need [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

Comment: Thanks RichieHindle. I tried respond.js but still having issues with IE7b and IE8 here: http://surfingthebluemarble.com/mnews.html.

Comment: You haven't put respond.js in the right place on your webserver.  The page is getting a 404 for http://surfingthebluemarble.com/respond-min.js (you **must** get into the habit of loading your page into a browser with its debug console open (press F12 in IE8/9, Chrome, or Firefox with Firebug installed).

Comment: Thanks RichieHindle. I put the unminified version of respond.min.js and the server appears to be loading it properly here: http://surfingthebluemarble.com/mnews2.html. However, IE7 and IE8 are still not stacking. Perhaps I need to do * and \9 here? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @umbregachoong: Your CSS needs to be in an external stylesheet, not in an inline `<style>` element.  (Please read the documentation for respond.js!)

Comment: Ok. Thanks RichieHindle. Will do. I will get back to you. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

IE Less than 9 doesn't support media queries out of the box.

use an extension like css3-mediaqueries-js or Respond.
https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/