# Best procedure to make responsive website work perfectly in IE7 & IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I would like to know the best way to make a HTML5 responsive website properly functioning in IE7 and IE8 as well without compromising any design.

I have gone through [responsive website issue in IE7 and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387569/responsive-website-issue-in-ie7-and-ie8) but rather than respond.js is there any other way to achieve this?

Also if I have some rounded corners used along with shadows in my blocks, if I use css3 it would not work in lower versions of IE9. Any best possible way to follow while working on these kind of requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is graceful degradation.  There is no magic bullet to solve all responsive issues across all browsers, including ie7/ie8.  Please post any code you are having problems with so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need so called polyfills for all technologies you're using if you don't want to use the principle of [graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system). Here's an [excellent overview](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) about basically all of them.

So, if you want IE old to support media queries you need a media query polyfill, respond.js is one of them. You could also use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which has a MQ polyfill included.

Comment: Thanks for your answer will have a look at them.